# NSRemoteView generates a strange message in the Log

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

When I run my sandboxed application in macOS Sierra, I find this message in the Log :

```
2016-09-21 12:08:42.787003 MyApp[1505:63581] warning: <NSRemoteView: 0x610000123160> determined it was necessary to configure <NSVBSavePanel: 0x103e002a0> to support remote view vibrancy
```

I don’t see this message in OS X 10.11.

It seems that this message appears when the application displays a NSSavePanel that covers the main window.

I’ve verified the .xib file that contains the window, I’ve searched in the documentation of Xcode and with Google but I didn’t find anything to solve the problem.

Added sept, 22

As soon as I declare a NSSavePanel in a method :

```
NSSavePanel     *panel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
```

The message is sent to the log.

Comment: I am currently having the same issue with a NSOpenPanel. The rest is as you described it. Will let you know if I figure out something new.

Comment: @Daniel I've submitted a bug report to Apple. I'll post here if I have an answer.

Comment: I am getting the same message with a CNContactPicker when I show it.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Open Panel myself. I also sometimes see the open panel get stuck after I select a file, nothing opens and the next time I only see the shell of open panel drawn. Very strange.

Comment: @Jacob Gorban I have seen that as well.

Comment: @Daniel we found a solution to Open Dialog not opening file. Or rather a bad workaround. It doesn't happen if I I delete the container for the application. So it's something from the old install. Also, it only happens in a non-Mac App Store build of an application but with enabled iCloud access, as gatekeeper now allows. Maybe only with a custom container but not sure about that yet. Anything special or similar about the cases when you saw this happen?

Comment: Same problem here. Does your app also crash or does it work fine after the error in the log? I'm investigating a number of crashes of my app on macOS Sierra.

Comment: Also getting the same warning: <NSRemoteView: 0x6000001235c0> determined it was necessary to configure <NSVBOpenPanel: 0x1007bead0> to support remote view vibrancy

Comment: @JacobGorban, Daniel and Mark, my macOS app was also getting stuck sometimes after selecting a file, not always, which is strange! But **after I've turned on the "App Sandbox" capability and selected "Read Only" on sandbox permissions under "User Selected File", my app never got stuck again!**

Regarding the original thread issue, I'm also getting that log message.

Comment: seems it is a serious problem, same warning here with NSOpenPanel, but that's much worst a crash after the panel closed, i need Read/Write folder access from the sandbox, the proper entitlements added via Xcode, badly need a solution :(

Answer (score 3):

macOS applications follow the pattern of sandbox. This means that you need to explicitly allow your application to read/write files, otherwise you encounter a permission problem that trigger some errors (one of them is in the form of the warning that you have underlined).

On the Capabilities tab of your application, be sure to enable at least one of the file access methods.

[image]

Comment: good thinking, but doesn't seem to be the problem. At least not for me.

Comment: Form me works only when all the entries in the .entitlement file are all set to Read/Write.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find answers here:

- [Accessibility API stops working after sandboxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871185/accessibility-api-stops-working-after-sandboxing)
- [Sandbox entitlement to script iTunes via NSAppleScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119076/sandbox-entitlement-to-script-itunes-via-nsapplescript)
- ['xattr' command not working inside sandbox app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38821844/xattr-command-not-working-inside-sandbox-app)

Also, may help:

```
<key>com.apple.security.scripting-targets</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.apple.terminal</string>
            <string>com.googlecode.iterm2</string>
            <string>com.apple.finder</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.shared-preference.read-write</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.apple.finder</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.apple.terminal</string>
        <string>com.googlecode.iterm2</string>
        <string>com.apple.finder</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

!!!
***If you try to submit to AppStore be informed that apple do not allow do this:***

- com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events and
- com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events